# What should the owner of `.` and `..` directories be?

Tags: linux, permissions, directory

A few questions about the `.` and `..` directories:

```
ls -la

drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 21 12:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 60 root root 4096 Mar 15 14:36 ..
```

1. Are `.` and `..` actually directories or are they like symlinks?
2. Which user/group should own those directories? For example, in a website document root directory where everything is owned by a specific user, should `.` and `..` also be owned by that user?
3. Will there be any problems if you change the ownership or permissions of those directories to something incorrect or overly strict?

Comment: You do know that "." means current folder and ".." means "parent folder"? As my answer states, most of the question makes no sense with this knowledge.

Comment: Yes, I understand their purpose, but from a technical point of view I don't really know how the system uses those "directories" and it makes little sense to me why they are listed as directories (or even listed at all) with permissions and ownership when in fact you are saying it makes no sense. I mean, I was inclined to believe the answer to my question would be along the lines of what you've said.

Comment: @TomTom In a way, it seems that `ls` showing those "directories" makes no sense - not my question.

Comment: Someone doing this professionally should understand the purpose of the "." and ".." directories and their semantics already.

Answer (score 4):

> Are . and .. actually directories or are they like symlinks?

I am inclined to say neither nor - they are special names that are processed by whatever (kernel? File system). They mean current and parent directory. Obviously they "are" real folders, but given a file system is a tree they are not real. Using symblinks for this special functionality would be tremendously wasteful.

> Which user/group should own those directories?

Noone. Or: Whoever owns the real folders, obviously. From here on the question makes little sense and seems to miss the fact that "." is the current folder and ".." is the parent folder, so assigning special permissions is just non nonsensical.

Comment: You say noone should own those and that it is nonsensical to give special permissions or ownership, but then why does the OS allow you to do so? That makes no sense to me. I feel my question in that context is perfectly valid.

Comment: No, i do not say noone should own those. I say that changing their permissions is non sensical in the way that they are basically already having the proper permission. In a website folder you should not have to change the permissions of "." and ".."

Comment: @BadHorsie Let's say your current working directory is `/home/horse/projects/toaster`. Now, if you want to make that directory writable, you could either run `chmod +x /home/horse/projects/toaster` or `chmod +x .`. You have multiple paths to the same resource for convenience, so you don't have to use absolute paths everywhere. However, under the hood, `..` will be expanded to `/home/horse/projects` and `.` will be expanded to `/home/horse/projects/toaster` (in this example). Given that, it doesn't make much sense to treat them as separate from the directories they alias.

Answer (score 4):

> Are `.` and `..` actually directories or are they like symlinks?

They are real directories in the regard that they are how *NIX shells (but also MS DOS)  represent the **current working directory** and the **parent directory** [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) respectively and those are obviously real directories.

If they confuse you, use the `-A` switch in `ls` to suppress listing them.

> Which user/group should own those directories?

That depends on your current working directory, i.e. in which directory you issued the `ls` command.

> Will there be any problems if you change the ownership or permissions of those directories to something incorrect or overly strict?

The actual impact depends on your current working directory, but generally changing ownerships and permissions to incorrect values leads to problems.

Answer (score 0):

They are real directories.  Specifically they are the entries in a directory which refer to itself and its parent.  That sounds like a trivial statement but it's not: directories contain the names of files (here 'file' includes 'directory' and any other object which may live in the filesystem), while the actual objects which describe the file (traditionally the inode on Unix) live elsewhere: directories merely point at these objects.  Directory entries do not contain permissions or ownership or anything else: they are merely names

And this answers the question: `.` is a name for the current directory: its permissions, ownership and everything else about it are *necessarily* the same as those of the current directory, because it *is* the current directory.  Similarly for `..`.